# Concurrency Management in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, queue

I have created a simple search engine :

```
public String search(Map<String, Object> params) {
    String result = /*search*/;
    return result;
}
```

this method performs the search process and returns the result (JSON), but there is a big problem...
since the search process is costly, if some users simultaneously perform the search process with the same keyword, the search process will be performed separately for each!

I have two options to avoid this :

1- `synchronized` : As you know, this will not solve the problem exactly...

2- using Shared Objects :

```
private static final ConcurrentHashMap<Object, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Locker<Object, String>>> CONCURRENT_SEARCHES = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public String search(Map<String, Object> params) {
    Object key = params.get("keyword");
    assert key != null;
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Locker<Object, String>> queue = CONCURRENT_SEARCHES.get(key);
    if (queue != null) {
        System.out.println("waiting");
        Locker<Object, String> locker = new Locker<>(key);
        queue.add(locker);
        locker.lock();
        String result = locker.getValue();
        return result == null ? "[]" : result;
    }
    System.out.println("new search");
    CONCURRENT_SEARCHES.put(key, (queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>()));
    String result = /*search*/;
    CONCURRENT_SEARCHES.remove(key);
    Locker<Object, String> locker;
    while ((locker = queue.poll()) != null) {
        locker.setValue(result);
        locker.unlock();
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is working really good but again there is a small problem.

**Testing**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String id = "1";
    ProcessSession session = ProcessManager.openSession(id);
    //...
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        service.submit(() -> session.search("keyword"));
    }
}
```

**output**:

```
new search
waiting
waiting
new search
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
```

**EDIT :**

```
public final class Locker<K, V> {

    private final Object o = new Object();
    private final K key;
    private V value;

    public Locker(K key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public K getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public V getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(V value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void lock() {
        synchronized (o) {
            try {
                o.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void lock(long timeout) {
        synchronized (o) {
            try {
                o.wait(timeout);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void unlock() {
        synchronized (o) {
            o.notify();
        }
    }

}
```

What is going wrong here? Can anyone suggest a better solution ?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, you cache searches, but not search results. So if there's no ongoing search for the keyword, a new one is started even if a similar search was done just before.

Comment: search result are not fixed and may be changed later for some reasons...

Comment: So what is the issue with the test run? Most of the searches are combined with previous ones. Isn't that what you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, problem solved :

```
private static final Map<Object, List<Locker<Object, String>>> CONCURRENT_SEARCHES = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();


public String search(Map<String, Object> params) {
    Object key = params.get("keyword");
    assert key != null;
    Locker<Object, String> locker = new Locker<>(key);
    if (isInProgress(key, locker)) {
        locker.lock();
        String result = locker.getValue();
        return result == null ? "[]" : result;
    }
    String result = /*search*/;
    finished(key, result);
    return result;
}

private static synchronized boolean isInProgress(Object key, Locker<Object, String> locker) {
    List<Locker<Object, String>> list = CONCURRENT_SEARCHES.get(key);
    if (list != null) {
        list.add(locker);
        return true;
    }
    CONCURRENT_SEARCHES.put(key, Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>()));
    return false;
}

private static synchronized void finished(Object key, String result) {
    Optional.of(CONCURRENT_SEARCHES)
            .map(searches -> searches.remove(key))
            .ifPresent(list -> {
                list.stream().forEach(locker -> {
                    locker.setValue(result);
                    locker.unlock();
                });
                list.clear();
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the concurrent collections stuff will only do the locking at a fine grained level so you are not getting much benefit anyway.

I would design the search a bit different. The idea here should be to design your `search` method in a way that makes two calls of it mutually exclusive. One way that come sin my mind is to use a produces consumer pattern here.

- `Search` method creates a worker for each call that is made to it and that worker is executed by a boundless executor service.
- Another way is to keep a queue of workers. `search` method creates workers and add them to the queue and another executor service keeps picking workers form queue to execute and return the results.

In all cases the idea is to make the instances of search operations mutually exclusive to each other. Also cache the stuff if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using locks and synchronized blocks, you can use flags to achieve better performance.

When first search happens , set a flag "In Progress" in a map with the search keyword as key.
So when repeated search come you can lookup this map and take a decision to wait or do a long polling to fetch the results from the first search.

Once search is complete cache the result if possible and remove the flag.

You can use socket programming to push your results to the users with same search keyword at the same time using advanced messaging. This would save resources and help achieve better performance.